# How to display activity in the ActionBar's tab?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using SupportLibrary. Here is my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab = bar.newTab();
        tab.setText("Tab 1");
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        bar.addTab(tab);
    }
```

How can I display some activity in the tab?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I display some activity in the tab?

You can't. First, that technique was deprecated three years ago. Second, `ActionBarActivity` does not extend the deprecated `ActivityGroup`.

You are welcome to use fragments for your tabs, though.

Comment: So, it's possible to use tabs without adding the library to support the application on older versions?

Comment: @MarkKorzhov: If you want to use action bar tabs on devices running API Level 10 and below, you can either use the `AppCompat` backport that you are using now or ActionBarSherlock. Both require a library, and neither allow activities to be the contents of tabs. **Nobody** should be trying to put activities in tabs anymore.